# Visa category for attending workshop (Turkish Visa)

Tags: visas, turkey, applications

I am currently a student in India and I am planning to attend workshop in Turkey for nearly 14 days. I have received acceptance letter from the organizing place. I am confused which Visa category should I apply. Is it Student Visa or any other type which fits my situation?

Comment: Could you please add information on the workshop, what it's for, and the name of the organizer? That will help to tell whether participants are eligible for a student, or other, visa.

Answer (score 1):

The Republic of [Turkey Ministry of Foreign Affairs (MFA)](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/general-information-about-turkish-visas.en.mfa) outlines two categories which match with your plans, Tourist and Student.

Among the activities permitted on a Tourist visa are conference, seminar, meeting; a two-week workshop fits within that category. The [Student-Education visa](http://www.studyinturkey.gov.tr/profiles/application/225) has a more rigorous process, such as a letter of enrollment from the relevant higher education institution, proof of funds for a living in Turkey (bank account, scholarship document), etc.

Another key difference: an e-visa is available for tourists, students requires consular application and interview. Absent additional information from you, whether the two-week workshop is organized by a university of which you are a student or intern, it is more likely that you would want a Tourist visa.

Again, the [MFA describes what to do](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/e-visa-is-ready-to-be-downloaded.en.mfa):

> **Visa Information For Foreigners**
>
> • The Electronic Visa (e-Visa) Application System was launched on 17 April 2013 by the Ministry of Foreign Affairs of the Republic of Turkey. This system allows visitors travelling to Turkey to easily obtain their e-Visas online (www.evisa.gov.tr), in approximately three minutes.
>
> Applicants just need to log on to www.evisa.gov.tr, provide the requested information, (after the application is approved) make online payment and download their e-Visa.
>
> • Please note that e-visa is only valid when the purpose of travel is tourism or commerce. Other purposes, such as work and study, require regular visa given by Embassies or Consulates.